# Convert QImage* to void* and vice versa

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, casting, qimage

I am working on C++ QT project which contains some modules communicating to each other through one controller module using a function with signature :

```
notify(QString stream_id, const void* stream, unsigned __int64 size)
```

So I am asking about how to convert a QT Data Type mainly **QImage* to void***, and vice versa, to send the data using the void pointer and its size,

i am trying to work with this code, but it`s not working:

```
    void* imageVoidPtr = static_cast<void*>(&image);

StreamListener::getInstance()->notify(QString("Stream_Name"),imageVoidPtr,sizeof(imageVoidPtr));
```

------------- Edit

And i am trying to retrieve the data using :

```
    void VideoView::receive(QString stream_id, const void* stream, unsigned __int64 size){
QByteArray data = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(stream), size);
QBuffer buffer(&data);
QImageReader reader(&buffer);
QImage img = reader.read();}
```

-------- Edit 2

What`s wrong with the code that the size of the Void* buffer is 4 or 12 (in case of sizeOf(QImage) ) and not giving the right size of the Image Bytes size,
and the received image in the receiver is empty (No errors appears).

Thanks

Comment: it's not working?

Comment: You might want to send the content of the image instead of a pointer to the `QImage`, depending on your framework, and depending on if this is sending in-process or to another process. Have a look at [`QImage::bits()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#bits) or `QImage::constBits`.

Comment: `sizeof(imageVoidPtr)` will simply evaluate to the size of a `void *` -- *not* anything relevant to the `QImage` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple solution for this question,

As while sending the data as a void* i have just give the function the address of the QImage to the notify function, and no need for the size:

```
 QImage image = CreateImage(imageStreamByteArray);
    StreamListener::getInstance()->notify(StreamsNames::VIDEO_DAT_IMAGE,&image,0);
```

And while in receiving i have use this type of casting, without using the size:

```
void VideoView::receive(QString stream_id, const void* stream, unsigned __int64 size){
    QImage *img = const_cast<QImage*>(reinterpret_cast<const QImage *>(stream));
   updateDisplay(img);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems like everyone misunderstood your question, because it was much simpler than anticipated. Turns out all you needed was to pass a pointer. Whether you pass any size or not is irrelevant if you end up not using it. Your initial problem was that you attempted to interpret a pointer value as an image, which is also why everyone assumed that the problem involves actual image data transfer, which it doesn't.

Comment: Keep in mind that using a `void*` however is prone to bugs, it may result in a dangling reference if the image object happens to get destroyed. Which is why it is preferable to pass it by value, it is a CoW object, meaning it will only involve a shallow copy, and the passed value is guaranteed to keep the underlying image data alive for as long as necessary, as it is reference counted. And you also avoid any memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

It is amazing that you expect this to work.

A pointer is just an integer number, that represents a memory address that may hold arbitrary data. Thus the pointer is always the same size, regardless of what it points to, because it is always a memory address, and it is always represented by a fixed number of bits, 32 in a 32bit build and 64 in a 64bit build.

`QImage` stores the data on the heap. The actual class is just a controller for the data. Therefore `sizeof()` will give you the same result regardless of how big the image is.

`QImage` already supports serialization and deserialization using `QDataStream`:

```
  QImage img(100, 100, QImage::Format_Mono); // original image
  QByteArray data; // data container
  QBuffer buffer(&data); // io device
  buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
  QDataStream stream(&buffer); // data stream
  stream << img; // save img to data 
  // you can now use the data.data() pointer, convert to void, and send data.size() number of bytes and put it into another byte array on the other side
  // then replicate the io dev and data stream steps too, omitted for brevity       
  QImage img2; // new image
  buffer.seek(0); // go to beginning of data
  stream >> img2; // read data into new image
  qDebug() << (img == img2) << data.size(); // true, it is the same content, size is 723 bytes, that includes the image format and raw data
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `QImage` [save method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#save-1):

```
QImage image;
QByteArray ba;
QBuffer buffer(&ba);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes image into ba in PNG format
```

You can now use the `QByteArray` underlying buffer like this:

```
void* imageVoidPtr = static_cast<void*>(ba.data());    
StreamListener::getInstance()->notify(QString("Stream_Name"), imageVoidPtr, ba.size());
```

If you need to set format-specific options (e.g. quality, for compressed formats), use a [QImageWriter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagewriter.html), instead:

```
QByteArray ba;
QBuffer buffer(&ba);
QImageWriter writer(&buffer, "JPG");
writer.setQuality(100); //max quality for jpeg
writer.write(image);
```

On the receiving end, everything should be fine, already (using a `QBuffer` and a `QImageReader`).

Answer (score 0):

At the first sight, this is the issue that apparently has caused your code not to work:

```
StreamListener::getInstance()->notify(QString("Stream_Name"),imageVoidPtr,sizeof(imageVoidPtr));
```

The last argument should be sizeof(QImage) instead like follows:

```
StreamListener::getInstance()->notify(QString("Stream_Name"),imageVoidPtr,sizeof(QImage));
```

Hope it works this way, but if not, it's much better if you mention what is wrong with your code, if it's not working what is the output or error?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it didn`t work, and i have edited the main post about what`s is wrong in the code in (Edit 2)